# Refresh razor page without reload using javascript/ jquery in asp.net core

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have one input and script to reload table in my page. In the input if I insert 1000 I want to reload page every second, without clicking any buttons.

This is what I tried :

```
<input id="txtRefresh" />

<script>
    document.redy(function () {
        $('tblRefresh').load();
        setInterval(function () {
            $('#tblRefresh').load();
        }, 'txtRefresh');
    });
</script>
```

Its `cshtml` razor page.

What I want to do is to insert the value of seconds in the `input` andrefresh the page based of the of the inserted value, without submiting any data.

Is it possible to do this? Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

---

**UPDATE**

I inserted this script:

```
<script>
    document.ready(function () {
        $('#refreshDIV').load('url/url/url');
        setInterval(function () {
            $('#refreshDIV').load('url/url/url');
        }, $('#txtRefresh').val());
    });
</script>
```

But it gaves me [error!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJCat.png)

`refreshDIV` is a div that I want to refresh

`txtRefresh` is the input from I insert the seconds

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var timeout = $("#txtRefresh").val();
     setTimeout(timeout, function() { location.href=""; });
});
```

but each time you will reload the page you will lose, the input.
You could send it through querystring like this:

```
location.href="?timeout="+timeout
```

and populate the input server side

Comment: Where should I put  `location.href="?timeout="+timeout` ? Sorry I newer used javascript

Comment: instead of locarion.href="" use location.href="?timeout="+timeout

Comment: did you change $("#input-id") with $("txtRefresh")? I'm editing the answer

Comment: Yes `var timeout = $("#txtRefresh").val();`    ;   `<input id="txtRefresh" type="number" />`  This is what I have

Answer (score 0):

This is just a string:

```
'txtRefresh'
```

If you want to [get the value of that element](https://api.jquery.com/val/), it would be more like this:

```
$('#txtRefresh').val()
```

You also have a typo in `document.ready` *and* in your first `#tblRefresh` selector (missing the `#`), and you aren't supplying `.load()` with [the URL you want to load](https://api.jquery.com/load/).  All together you appear to be trying to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tblRefresh').load('/some/url');
    setInterval(function () {
        $('#tblRefresh').load('/some/url');
    }, $('#txtRefresh').val());
});
```

A couple things to note:

1. The value `/some/url` is of course a placeholder in this sample code.  Whatever URL you want to use in your application is up to you.
2. Calling `.load()` will place the *entire response* of that URL into the target element.  If you want only a subset of that response, you can add selectors to `.load()`.  For example:

   `$('#tblRefresh').load('/some/url #someElement');`

This would tell `.load()` to grab all the content from `/some/url` and then only select from it the content of `#someElement` to place in `#tblRefresh`.  The performance could still potentially be slow as all of the content from the URL is still downloaded.  To address performance or for finer control over data, consider returning JSON data from the server and using `.ajax()` to fetch that data instead of using `.load()` to reload all of the HTML (when only the data has changed).

Comment: What is `#someElement` ?

Comment: @kvacka: It’s an example of a selector, much like the other jQuery selectors you already use elsewhere.  If you want to filter specific content from the response, you’d use a selector there to identify that content.  (The linked jQuery documentation includes more info and examples.)

Comment: I can't understand why it gaves me this error : https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJCat.png

Comment: @kvacka: It was an error I hadn’t spotted in your original code.  Check the updated answer.